# How do I call a remote script in a Chrome Extension that only interacts with the extension popup/sidebar

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am attempting to load a remote js file into my popup/sidebar using the following code

```
const newScript = document.createElement('script')
newScript.src = 'https://mycompany.com/dist/myscript.js'
const myTarget = document.getElementById('offcanvas')
myTarget.appendChild(newScript)
```

Which results in the following errors

> Refused to load the script 'https://mycompany.com/dist/myscript.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

> Refused to load the script 'https://mycompany.com/dist/myscript.j' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' 'inline-speculation-rules' http://localhost:* [http://127.0.0.1:*"](http://127.0.0.1:*%22). Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

If I instead download the js file and include it in the extension bundle like this though it works as expected

```
const newScript = document.createElement('script')
newScript.src = 'myscript.js'
const myTarget = document.getElementById('offcanvas')
myTarget.appendChild(newScript)
```

I prefer to call the remote file so the latest version is always being referenced, but it's not clear to me how to resolve this.

Can someone point me in the right direction please.

Comment: It's forbidden in ManifestV3. You should either include it with your extension or run inside a [sandboxed iframe](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/sandbox/).

Comment: @wOxxOm Okay, good to know although that cuts me off from localStorage which is annoying.  Thanks

Comment: You can use the standard web messaging to pass the data to the sandbox.